# Installing Windows CE on a x86 embedded device

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

What is the general procedure to install Windows CE on an embedded device (like the [eBox4300](http://www.embeddedpc.net/eBox4300/tabid/190/Default.aspx)? Is there an equivalent of the PXE boot in windows so that I can boot the device over a network, and then install Windows CE on it?

I have googled extensively, and the only thing I've gathered is that there is a dos bootloader that if present (preloaded) will enable me to do this. But since the flashdisk was formatted, this isn't possible. And I'm unable to get my hands on this bootloader.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I did figure out how to do this eventually. The steps I followed were as follows:

1. Make a bootable USB drive using [HP Drive Key Boot Utility](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&swItem=MTX-UNITY-I23839&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) (via [bootdisk.com](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm) Method 2)
2. Format the flash disk in the device.
3. Make the flash disk in the device bootable using [MBRTool](http://www.diydatarecovery.nl/mbrtool.htm) (This is necessary if you installed GRUB on the disk. The MBR needs to be overwritten)
4. From the Win CE installation folder, from `drive:\<path to wince installation>\PLATFORM\CEPC\SRC\BOOTLOADER\DOS\BOOTDISK`copy all files and paste it to the flash disk in the device (These files always comes with Win CE installation)
5. Put your build of Win CE - `EBOOT.BIN` in the flash disk on the device (This will be your custom Win CE image)
6. Remove the USB drive, and boot the device. Your new build of Win CE should boot up.